# String Split to Unique Columns Depends on Name of the series

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting started with pandas and I have one column like this:

```
0 | Layer 7 Data
-------------------------------------------
1 | HTTP Request Method: GET, HTTP URI: /ucp/
2 | HTTP Return Code: 200, HTTP User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0
3 | HTTP Return Code: 401, HTTP Request Method: POST
```

After I string split and expand it to different columns by `df = df["Layer 7 Data"].str.split(",", expand=True)`, I get some columns like this:

```
0 | 0                        | 1
------------------------------------------------------------
1 | HTTP Request Method: GET | HTTP URI: /ucp/
2 | HTTP Return Code: 200    | HTTP User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0
3 | HTTP Return Code: 401    | HTTP Request Method: POST
```

However, I want it to have separate columns for unique values, return Null for that cell if it doesn't match:

```
0 | 0                         | 1               | 2                     |3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | HTTP Request Method: GET  | HTTP URI: /ucp/ |Null                   | Null
2 | Null                      | Null            | HTTP Return Code: 200 | HTTP User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0
3 | HTTP Request Method: POST | Null            | HTTP Return Code: 401 | Null
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list cmprehension:

```
L = [{y.split(': ', 1)[0]:y for y in x.split(", ")} for x in df["Layer 7 Data"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index)
print (df)
         HTTP Request Method         HTTP URI       HTTP Return Code  \
0   HTTP Request Method: GET  HTTP URI: /ucp/                    NaN   
1                        NaN              NaN  HTTP Return Code: 200   
2  HTTP Request Method: POST              NaN  HTTP Return Code: 401   

                 HTTP User-Agent  
0                            NaN  
1  HTTP User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0  
2                            NaN
```

Or:

```
L = [dict([y.split(': ', 1) for y in x.split(", ")]) for x in df["Layer 7 Data"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index)
print (df)
  HTTP Request Method HTTP URI HTTP Return Code HTTP User-Agent
0                 GET    /ucp/              NaN             NaN
1                 NaN      NaN              200     Mozilla/5.0
2                POST      NaN              401             NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract the key/values and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the DataFrame:

```
out = (df['Layer 7 Data']
 .str.extractall(r'\s*([^,:]+):\s*([^:,]+)')
 .droplevel(1).pivot(columns=0, values=1).rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
  HTTP Request Method HTTP Return Code HTTP URI HTTP User-Agent
1                 GET              NaN    /ucp/             NaN
2                 NaN              200      NaN     Mozilla/5.0
3                POST              401      NaN             NaN
```

Intermediate of `extractall`:

```
df['Layer 7 Data'].str.extractall(r'\s*([^,:]+):\s*([^:,]+)')

                           0            1
  match                                  
1 0      HTTP Request Method          GET
  1                 HTTP URI        /ucp/
2 0         HTTP Return Code          200
  1          HTTP User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0
3 0         HTTP Return Code          401
  1      HTTP Request Method         POST
```